# Sharing a pojo objrct between two wars deployed in different servers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war

I have two Wars deployed in two different servers. I have to share a common pojo object between the two Wars. How to share a Object between two wars and Where can I put this Pojo Jar?

Also I am using the request dispatcher sendRedirect method to pass a request from one War to another. Do we have any other better approach to pass the request from one war to another?

Comment: What is all this intended to achieve for the end user, what application feature does it provide?  As an aside, always include that information.  See this post on the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more details of why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a pojo in a jar and put that jar in a common location so that classpath on both the servers can point to that common location (folder). Though the correct approach would be to include that pojo into individual war.